# User defined function - multiple data frame output

Tags: r

I want to create a function that will execute all my lines of code. There is one input and multiple outputs as shown below:

```
Region_Analysis_Function <- function(Input_Region){
  Subset_Region_Data = subset(Region_Data, Region == Input_Region )
  Seniority_Region = table(Subset_Region_Data$Seniority)
  Seniority_Region = as.data.frame(Seniority_Region)
  {Subset_Region_Data, Seniority_Region}
}
```

The input is a data frame called "Region_Data." I want this function to print both "Subset_Region_Data" and "Seniority_Region" as 2 different data frames.

Any way of printing multiple outputs?

Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: You can use `list(Subset_Region_Data, Seniority_Region)` to get the output in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list is what you are looking for here.

You can do this:

```
my_two_df_function <- function(){
  df1 <- data.frame()
  df2 <- data.frame()
  return(list(df1=df1, df2=df2))
}
df_list <- my_two_df_function()
df_list$df1
df_list$df2
```

You can mix types with a list too...

```
my_two_df_function <- function(){
  df1 <- data.frame()
  df2 <- data.frame()
  return(list(df1=df1, df2=df2, error_msg="none"))
}
df_list <- my_two_df_function()

df_list$error_msg
```

Comment: Oh man, didn't mean to step on any toes. Was just trying to explain why a list is the way to go in a little more depth.